# Minimum of a finite Fourier sum

Tags: summation, fourier-series, maxima-minima, convolution, roots-of-unity

I would like to find the minimum $$m_N = \min_{0\leq x\leq 2\pi}  \{ f_N(x) \} \quad \hbox{ with } \quad f_N(x)=\frac{N}{2}+\sum_{k=1}^{N-1} (N-k) \cos(k x)$$ for all integers $N\geq 2$. It looks like it should be $m_N=0$ for all $N$ but I'm not able to prove it. Can you help me at least with some insight on how to address this problem? Thank you

Comment: I believe you can have a closed form formula for the sum.

Comment: Feijer kernel is nonnegative

Comment: This is just the Fejer kernel https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fej%C3%A9r_kernel

Comment: THANK YOU very much! I didn't know about the Fejer kernel 